# How to export a function with Webpack and use it in an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a file called `index.js`:

```
"use strict";

var $ = require("jquery");
window.jQuery = $;

export function foo() {
    console.log('hello world');
}
```

And in the same directory, `webpack-config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        filename: './dist.js'
    },
    mode: "development"
};
```

And finally I have an `index.html` file which loads my bundled JavaScript, and tries to use the exported function definition...

```
<script src="/media/js/dist/dist.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    foo();
</script>
```

When I run `webpack`, I see no output errors.

But when I load my HTML page, I see:

```
(index):211 Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined
   at (index):211
```

What am I doing wrong? The `dist.js` file is loading perfectly OK.

Comment: Just like you did with jQuery: `window.foo = foo;`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a `library` property to your output configuration:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        filename: './dist.js',
        library: 'myLibrary'
    },
    mode: "development"
};
```

Then in `index.js`, you should be able to call `foo()` like so:

```
myLibrary.foo();
```

For this to work it's important that the `foo()` function is being exported with `export function` and **not** `export default function`

Comment: I just get `Uncaught TypeError: myLibrary.foo is not a function`

Comment: I've tried logging `myLibrary` from `index.html` and it does exist: `Module {__esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}`. It just doesn't have `foo` attached. What's going on?!

Comment: Here's the content of `dist.js` in case that helps. https://pastebin.com/raw/L96ARXey

Comment: Ah - if I add `libraryTarget: 'window', libraryExport: 'default'`, and amend my function to `export default function foo`, then I can call `myLibrary()` and it will call `foo()`. BUT - there seems to be no way to define more than one function in this file.

Comment: @Richard It looks to me like in index.js you have `export default function foo()` instead of `export function foo()` like you said in the question. If you want it to be `myLibrary.foo()` then you need to use `export function` and not `export default function`.

Comment: Changed the key `library` to `libraryTarget` and worked