# Plain Vanilla JS + CapacitorJS

Tags: javascript, hybrid-mobile-app, capacitor

I’m a web developer and new to apps so excuse my ignorance and apologies if this is a stupid question.

I’ve setup a blank capacitorjs project, got all my emulators working  (Android and iOS/Xcode) etc and now I cannot get the core plugins to work inside index.html.

Also when I include a locally hosted jQuery file in index.html I get localhost:// errors. Basically, not found.. for everything! When I link to the CDN it works.

My objective is to get my project to a blank slate where the index.html can make capacitor api calls eg alert(device info) etc. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

**Index.html:**

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="capacitor.js"></script>




<head></head>

<body>

<button id="button" style="width:500px; height:500px; background-color:gold;">TEST</button>


</body>


<script>

$("#button").on("click", (event) => {
  // execute your functions


const info = await Device.getInfo();
console.log(info);



  })


</script>
```

**capacitor.config.json**

```js
import { Camera } from '@capacitor/camera';
import { CameraResultType } from '@capacitor/camera';
import { Device } from '@capacitor/device';

    const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  "appId": "com.zenithapp.app",
  "appName": "Zenith Mobile App",
  "webDir": "www",
  "bundledWebRuntime": true

};

export default config;
```

**Result in XCODE console when compile and run my Capacitorjs app:**

```html
 ⚡️  ------ STARTUP JS ERROR ------

⚡️  SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Device'. Expected ';' after variable declaration.
⚡️  URL: capacitor://localhost
⚡️  localhost:27:0

⚡️  See above for help with debugging blank-screen issues
⚡️  [error] - {"line":27,"sourceURL":"capacitor://localhost"}
⚡️  WebView loaded
```

Comment: Please post actual code and not images of code.

Comment: Thank you for looking E Maggini, I have included the code to see if anyone has ideas where I'm going wrong.

Also important to note when I change the CDN jquery to my local file, it can't find it, I get the same localhost error. 

I have a feeling that's the issue - but no idea where to look to correct it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is scrolling RN with a similar issue, this is fixed, I deleted my capacitorJS container (backed up my www/root HTML folders) and started again, this time following this tutorial below which is more comprehensive than the one on the official site (what a surprise)

https://medium.com/@SmileFX/a-complete-guide-building-a-capacitorjs-application-using-pure-javascript-and-webpack-37d00f11720d

Also this one:

[How to export a function with Webpack and use it in an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56102640/how-to-export-a-function-with-webpack-and-use-it-in-an-html-page)

Hope this helps. I needed to use webpack, then export the functions so they can be called anywhere in index.html. Working cross platform Vanilla-ish JS.

I can now put a nice simple single-page-web-app that I actually know how to code and maintain + access the phone's APIs, and not have to deal with some hell-ish bloated framework like react or angular that I just can't be bothered with right now